# SSMS 2008 Object exploer not showing

Tags: ssms

Has anyone seen this issue. I am using SSMS 2008 (x64 Version   10.0.5768.0) on Win 2008 R2 machine. Management studio crashed and then when I launch it, it doesn't show Object Explorer even when I hit F8 or select it from View. The only time it works is when I select full screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind.. I just fixed it... something might have been corrupt in my local profile setting. Renamed the SQL folder in Local and Roaming of App folder and it is working now.

Thanks!

Comment: You should mark this as the answer for people in the future who experience the same issue. :-)